# App installed but icon doesn't appear in launcher screen or app list

Tags: android, android-manifest, system, android-tv

Android system level settings application is installed but icon doesn't appear in launcher screen.I have shared piece of manifest file.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_settings_color_48dp"
    android:label="@string/settings_app_name"
    android:banner="@drawable/ic_launcher_banner_settings"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Settings"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainSettings"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Settings.Transparent"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:label="@string/settings_app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.settings.SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="3"
            android:label="@string/launcher_settings_app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_launcher_icon" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_SETTINGS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: do you see a default icon or no icon at all .

Comment: Icon is not visible at all,I have checked in installed applications and app is installed.

Comment: Are you making an App for Android TV ??

Comment: Yes ,android version is 7.1.

Comment: So your app won't support Android Devices and will support only Android TV. Is my assumption correction ? Or do you want to support both TV and Android phones/tablets ?

Comment: No ,I am developing for TV .Thought command prompt app is opening perfectly.Main thing is installed app in not visible in launcher app.

Comment: Try replacing your intent-filter with this - <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_SETTINGS" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: I have changed but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### Declare a TV Activity
>
> An application intended to run on TV devices must declare a launcher activity for TV in its manifest. It uses a [`CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER) intent filter to do this. This filter identifies your app as being enabled for TV, and lets Google Play identify it as a TV app. When a user selects your app on their TV home screen, this intent identifies which activity to launch.
>
> [...]
>
> > **Caution:** If you do not include the [`CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER) intent filter in your app, it is not visible to users running Google Play on TV devices. Also, if your app does not have this filter when you use developer tools to load it onto a TV device, the app does not appear in the TV user interface.

Source: [Getting Started with TV Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html)

So an activity has to have this intent filter to appear in a TV launcher:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

---

The code which you probably copied from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TvSettings/+/lollipop-dev/Settings/AndroidManifest.xml) defines system settings entry point in launcher.

If you're building some kind of systm level app you should mention that in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: You will also want to make sure you have a banner defined for your app. The banner should be 320 x 180 px. Reference:
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#banner

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your launcher activity in android_manifest

You can add into your splash screen or Main Activity

```
android:banner="@drawable/main_logo"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

AND

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
```

IT WILL LOOK LIKE THIS

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivitySplash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:banner="@drawable/main_logo"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```